# I didn't true use order by in linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Hi i develop web app with c#. I have sql query and i convert to linq but it's not working true because of order by

My sql query

```
Select TOP 3 HastalikIsmi From Hastaliklar group by HastalikIsmi order by Count(*) desc
```

My linq

```
public List<HastalikDto> GetHastalikDto()
    {
        using (SirketDBContext context = new SirketDBContext())
        {
            var result = from hastalik in context.Hastaliklar                            
                         group hastalik by hastalik.HastalikIsmi into isim
                         
                         select new HastalikDto { HastalikIsmi = isim.Key };                         

            return result.OrderBy(h => h.HastalikIsmi).Take(3).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var groups = from hastalik in context.Hastaliklar                            
 group hastalik by hastalik.HastalikIsmi into isim
 orderby isim.Count() descending                  
 select new HastalikDto { HastalikIsmi = isim.Key }; return groups.Take(3);`

Comment: @AluanHaddad  can you look this problem ? please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479655/convert-this-sql-query-to-an-equivalent-linq-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do the order by on the count of each group and take the 3 with the highest count.

```
var result = context.Hastaliklar
    .GroupBy(x => x.HastalikIsmi)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
    .Select(grp => grp.Key)
    .Take(3)
    .ToList();
```